# toggle multi password visibility - php

Tags: php, passwords, toggle

i have a form that It stores a number of passwords in mysql

we need to hide pass, And whenever we need, click on the desired password

But the problem is that by clicking the toggle, the first password is displayed

for example: (This is not the main source)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the radio button to toggle between password visibility:</p>

Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

<br>
Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i used `id="'.$row["id"].'"`  but that is not enogh

Answer (score 0):

For both `onclick` you specify the same function which refer to id `myInput`. There are 2 id's with that name.

You should not use the same id multiple times `id="myInput"`.

What you could do is create unique id's and pass those to your function.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the radio button to toggle between password visibility:</p>

  Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput1">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('myInput1')">Show Password

  <br> Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput2">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('myInput2')">Show Password
</body>

</html>
```

To use `id="'.$row["id"].'"` you could loop your mysql results and for each result write the checkbox and password inputs. Then you could use the id (if it is unique) which contains the value from mysql and use that instead of 'myInput1'

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I use id="'.$row["id"].'"  For id. Id must read from mysql. But this script can't do this.

Comment: You could loop your mysql results and for each result write the checkbox and password inputs. Then you could use the id from mysql instead of 'myInput1'